# Formulario en php que no llegan los datos a la dirección de correo

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente formulario en php en el que  se require tener inicio  de sesión y no se que ocurre, porque antes si funcionaba bien y llegaban los datos a las 2 direcciones de correo, pero ahora llega el formulario solamente al email que introduce el usuario y a pesar de rellenar los campos, solo llega el nombre y los comentarios. Y al otro email web@web.es que  es donde tengo que recibir el formulario no llega nada. Durante un tiempo funcionaba ok, pero ahora no esta funcionando bien.
Aquí iría la parte del código que pertenece al inicio de sesion: he puesto texto ficticio Esto es algo que se puede manejar en el sitio a través de su cuenta. Continúe editando su publicación para eliminar dicha información y reemplazarla con texto/datos/código ficticio que cumple el mismo propósito (tenga cuidado de no romper el contexto de la publicación, especialmente si las respuestas ya están presentes) y luego marque la publicación para atención del moderador. Tanto en la marca como en las descripciones de edición, intente ser lo más descriptivo posible (es decir, mencione "IP y direcciones de correo electrónico eliminadas" o "dirección de correo electrónico y contraseña eliminadas").

Si las respuestas ya usaban información confidencial antes de que se diera cuenta y la editara, haga lo mismo con ellas.

```
            
        <p>Hola <?php echo $username; ?>, has accedido de forma satisfactoria</p>
        <a href="?logout=true">Cerrar sesión</a>
        
        <?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "web@web.es"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
   $localizacion = $_POST['localizacion'];
   $codigopostal = $_POST['codigopostal'];
     $idioma = $_POST['idioma'];
         $asignatura = $_POST['asignatura'];
            $modalidad = $_POST['modalidad'];
             $precio = $_POST['precio'];
            $acepto = $_POST['acepto'];
    $subject = "Form submission";
    $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
   $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " " . "\n\n" . $localizacion .  "\n\n" . $codigopostal  . "\n\n" . $idioma  . "\n\n" . $asignatura  . "\n\n" .  $modalidad . "\n\n" . $precio . "\n\n" . $acepto . "\n\n". "Mensaje recibido:" . "\n\n" .$_POST['message'];
    $message2 = "Copia el mensaje" . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); 
    //echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
    header("Location:https://www.ernd.es/profesores/formulariodecarga.php");
 
    }
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Formulario de profesores</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
 
  font-size: 14px;
}
</style>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
<body>


<br><br><form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 
Nombre<br>
<input type="text" name="first_name" required><br><br>
Apellidos<br><input type="text" name="last_name" required><br><br>
Email<br> <input type="email" name="email" required><br><br>
Localización<br><input type="text" name="localizacion"><br><br>
Código postal<br><input type="text" name="codigopostal"><br><br>
<select name="idioma">
        <option value="">Seleccionar idioma</option>
       <option value="Aleman"> Alemán</option>
     <option value="Chino"> Chino</option>
      <option value="Español">Español para extranjeros</option>
      <option value="Frances">Francés</option>
      <option value="Hebreo">Hebreo </option>                                   
     <option value="Ingles"> Inglés</option>
      <option value="Italiano">Italiano</option>
      <option value="Japones">Japonés</option>
      <option value="Noruego">Noruego</option>
     <option value="Polaco"> Polaco</option>
      <option value="Portugues">Portugués</option>
      <option value="Sueco">Sueco</option>

                                </select>
                                <br><br>
                                 <select name="asignatura">
                                    <option value="">Seleccionar asignatura</option>
       <option value="Biologia"> Biología</option>
     <option value="Dibujo"> Dibujo técnico</option>
      <option value="Geologia">Geología</option>
      <option value="Historia">Historia</option>
      <option value="Informatica">Informática </option>                                   
     <option value="Lengua"> Lengua</option>
      <option value="Matematicas">Matemáticas</option>
      <option value="Quimica">Química</option>
      <option value="Robotica">Robótica</option>
     <option value="Polaco"> Polaco</option>

                                </select>
                                <br><br>
                       <select name="modalidad" required>
                                    <option value="">Seleccionar modalidad</option>
       <option value="Online">Online</option>
     <option value="Presencial"> Presencial</option>
      <option value="Online-presencial">Online y presencial</option>

                                </select><br><br>
      

Precio hora<br><input type="text" name="precio" required><br><br>

              
Descripción:<br><textarea rows="20" name="message" cols="40" maxlength="1300" required></textarea><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar"><br><br>
 <input type="reset" value="Borrar"><br><br>
  <input type="checkbox" value="acepto" required> Acepto la <a href="https://www.wwwww.es/politica-privacidad.php">política de privacidad</a>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Aquí iría la function display_login_form() con el correpondiente formulario para poder acceder a la parte restringida, de esta manera ya solo queda el formulario para enviar y recibir los datos desde una cuenta de correo.

Comment: Pipe intente de diferentes formas poner el código pero no había manera, de ahí que cree un archivo de .txt para que lo visualices, gracias.

Comment: Ya he visto como los has puesto con las 3 comas ``` no encontraba la manera de hacerlo, para otra vez ya lo se. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

A mi me funciona perfecto, salieron ambos emailes. Quizás el servidor de email remoto tiene en lista negra la IP de tu servidor Web por exceso de pruebas.
Hay sitios Web donde metes la IP de tu servidor y te dice si estás en listas negras. También puedes probar a mandarlo a una cuenta de Gmail, y ver si te llega. También mira en la carpeta de SPAM.
Te adjunto Log de mi Server, para que veas que salir, salen:

```
2023-07-14 19:44:15 1qKMpy-0000Kq-39 => chema@*****.net F=<smart@*****.es> R=lookuphost T=remote_smtp S=1363 H=mail.*****.net [**.***.**.**] X=TLS1.2:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:128 CV=no C="250 OK id=1qKMpz-00046e-0K"
2023-07-14 19:44:15 1qKMpy-0000Kq-39 **Completed**

2023-07-14 19:44:15 1qKMpz-0000Kt-02 => chema****@gmail.com F=<smart@*****.es> R=lookuphost T=remote_smtp S=1314 H=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com [142.250.110.27] X=TLS1.2:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:128 CV=yes C="250 2.0.0 OK DMARC:Quarantine 1689356655 s11-20020a05600c384b00b003fb
dbe46963si1058077wmr.28 - gsmtp"
2023-07-14 19:44:15 1qKMpz-0000Kt-02 **Completed**
```

Comment: Gracias Chema, si te ha llegado es que funciona bien. Lo que si es verdad es que estoy comprobando todos los perfiles y que los formularios funcionen perfectamente y de ahí que este en la lista negra yo mismo. He probado con una cuenta de correo que pertenecería al usuario y otra en hotmail. En la del usuario llega el formulario completo, en la de hotmail no llega nada. Debe ser que yo mismo estoy en la lista negra. Me quedo más tranquilo si me dices que funciona ok. Muchas gracias

Comment: Los de Hotmail (outlook) son muy tiquismiquis con el tema del email, el "mailto" es propenso a ser calificado como SPAM. Por que no usas la clase  PHPMailer? 
De esa manera evitarías ser Spamizado, ya que usa para el envío cuentas reales.